# Recycler view not showing after parsing json data using Volley

Tags: android, json

Inside my tab bar i want to show my data in Recycler view by using json parsing using volley library. I parsed the data and it showing in toast perfectly.But in Recycler view its not showing Here is my codes.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener;

import info.tatwa.adupter.AdupterBoxOffice;
import info.tatwa.extras.Keys;
import info.tatwa.extras.UrlEndPoint;
import info.tatwa.login.L;
import info.tatwa.model.Movies;
import info.tatwa.network.MyApplication;
import info.tatwa.network.VolleySingleton;
import info.tatwa.newnav.R;
import info.tatwa.extras.UrlEndPoint.*;
import info.tatwa.extras.Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.*;

public class FragmentBoxOffice extends Fragment {
private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private AdupterBoxOffice adupterBoxOffice;
private ArrayList<Movies>listMovie = new ArrayList<>();
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
public static final String ROTET_TOMATO_URL_BOX_OFFICE="My url is here"
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private RecyclerView listMovieHits;

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;


/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentBoxOffice.
 */

 public static FragmentBoxOffice newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentBoxOffice fragment = new FragmentBoxOffice();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
 }
public static String getRequestUrl(int limit){
    //ROTET_TOMATO_URL_BOX_OFFICE+"?apikey="+          MyApplication.ROTET_TOMATO_API_KEY+"&limit="+limit;
    return UrlEndPoint.URL_BOX_OFFICE +
            UrlEndPoint.URL_CHAR_QUASTIAN+
            UrlEndPoint.URL_CHAR_PAREM_APIKEY +
            MyApplication.ROTET_TOMATO_API_KEY +
            UrlEndPoint.URL_CHAR_APPEND+
            UrlEndPoint.URL_CHAR_PAREM_LIMIT + limit;
}

public FragmentBoxOffice() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getsInstance();
    requestQueue = volleySingleton.getmRequestQueue();
    senJsonRequest();
}
public void senJsonRequest(){
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getRequestUrl(10), (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            paresJSONResponse(response);
            listMovie =paresJSONResponse(response);
            adupterBoxOffice.setMovieList(listMovie);
            L.t(getActivity(), response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error"+error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
public ArrayList<Movies> paresJSONResponse(JSONObject response){
    ArrayList<Movies> listMovie = new ArrayList<>();
    if(response ==null|| response.length()==0 ){
        return null;
    }
    try {
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        JSONArray arrayMovie = response.getJSONArray(Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.KEY_MOVIES);
        Log.v("BIKASH", "JSON Object id" + arrayMovie);
        for(int i = 0; i<arrayMovie.length();i++){
           JSONObject currentMovies= arrayMovie.getJSONObject(i);
            Long id =currentMovies.getLong(Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.KEY_ID);
            String title=currentMovies.getString(Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.KEY_TITLE);
            JSONObject objectReleaseDates=currentMovies.getJSONObject(Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.KEY_RELEASE_DATES);
            String releaseDate=null;
            if(objectReleaseDates.has(Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.KEY_THEATER)){
                releaseDate = objectReleaseDates.getString(Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.KEY_THEATER);
            }
            else {
                releaseDate="NA";
            }
            int audianceRatting=-1;
            JSONObject objectRatting = currentMovies.getJSONObject(Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.KEY_RATINGS);
            {
                if(objectRatting.has(Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.KEY_AUDIENCE_SCORE)){
                    audianceRatting=objectRatting.getInt(Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.KEY_AUDIENCE_SCORE);
                }

            }
            String synuypsis = currentMovies.getString(Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.KEY_SYNOPSIS);
            String urlThumbnel = null;
            JSONObject objPoster = currentMovies.getJSONObject(Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.KEY_THUMBNAIL);
            if(objPoster.has(Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.KEY_THUMBNAIL)){
                urlThumbnel = objPoster.getString(Keys.EndpointBoxOffice.KEY_THUMBNAIL);
            }

            Movies movie =new Movies();
            movie.setId(id);
            movie.setTitle(title);
           Date date = dateFormat.parse(releaseDate);
            movie.setReleaseDateTheater(date);
            movie.setAudienceScore(audianceRatting);
            movie.setSynopsis(synuypsis);
            movie.setUrlThumbnail(urlThumbnel);

            listMovie.add(movie);
          //  data.append(id + "\n");
        }
        L.t(getActivity(),listMovie.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listMovie;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_box_office, container, false);
    listMovieHits =(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.listMovieHits);
    listMovieHits.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    adupterBoxOffice = new AdupterBoxOffice(getActivity());
    listMovieHits.setAdapter(adupterBoxOffice);
    senJsonRequest();
    return view;
}
```

}

My Adupter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import info.tatwa.model.Movies;
import info.tatwa.myfragment.FragmentBoxOffice;
import info.tatwa.network.VolleySingleton;
import info.tatwa.newnav.R;


public class AdupterBoxOffice extends         RecyclerView.Adapter<AdupterBoxOffice.ViewHolderBoxOffice> {
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
FragmentBoxOffice activity;

private ArrayList<Movies> listMovie = new ArrayList<>();
private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public AdupterBoxOffice(Context context){
    layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    volleySingleton=VolleySingleton.getsInstance();
    imageLoader = volleySingleton.getImageLoader();

}
public void setMovieList(ArrayList<Movies>listMovie){
 this.listMovie = listMovie;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0,listMovie.size());
}
@Override
public ViewHolderBoxOffice onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_list_itom,parent,false);
    ViewHolderBoxOffice viewHolder =new ViewHolderBoxOffice(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderBoxOffice holder, int position) {
    Movies currentMovie =listMovie.get(position);
    holder.movieTitle.setText(currentMovie.getTitle());
    holder.movieReleaseDate.setText(currentMovie.getReleaseDateTheater().toString());
    holder.movieRatting.setRating(currentMovie.getAudienceScore()/20.0f);
   String urlThumbnel = currentMovie.getUrlThumbnail();
    if(urlThumbnel!=null){
        imageLoader.get(urlThumbnel, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                holder.imagePoster.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listMovie.size();
}

static class ViewHolderBoxOffice extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView imagePoster;
    private TextView movieTitle;
    private TextView movieReleaseDate;
    private RatingBar movieRatting;
    public ViewHolderBoxOffice(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imagePoster=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieThumbnail);
        movieTitle =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);
        movieReleaseDate=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieReleaseDate);
        movieRatting=(RatingBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieAudienceScore);
    }
}
```

}

And My Model class

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.util.Date;




public class Movies{ 
private long id;
private String title;
private Date releaseDateTheater;
private int audienceScore;
private String synopsis;
private String urlThumbnail;
private String urlSelf;
private String urlCast;
private String urlReviews;
private String urlSimilar;

public Movies() {

}



public Movies(long id,
             String title,
             Date releaseDateTheater,
             int audienceScore,
             String synopsis,
             String urlThumbnail,
             String urlSelf,
             String urlCast,
             String urlReviews,
             String urlSimilar) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.releaseDateTheater = releaseDateTheater;
    this.audienceScore = audienceScore;
    this.synopsis = synopsis;
    this.urlThumbnail = urlThumbnail;
    this.urlSelf = urlSelf;
    this.urlCast = urlCast;
    this.urlReviews = urlReviews;
    this.urlSimilar = urlSimilar;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public Date getReleaseDateTheater() {
    return releaseDateTheater;
}

public void setReleaseDateTheater(Date releaseDateTheater) {
    this.releaseDateTheater = releaseDateTheater;
}

public int getAudienceScore() {
    return audienceScore;
}

public void setAudienceScore(int audienceScore) {
    this.audienceScore = audienceScore;
}

public String getSynopsis() {
    return synopsis;
}

public void setSynopsis(String synopsis) {
    this.synopsis = synopsis;
}

public String getUrlThumbnail() {
    return urlThumbnail;
}

public void setUrlThumbnail(String urlThumbnail) {
    this.urlThumbnail = urlThumbnail;
}

public String getUrlSelf() {
    return urlSelf;
}

public void setUrlSelf(String urlSelf) {
    this.urlSelf = urlSelf;
}

public String getUrlCast() {
    return urlCast;
}

public void setUrlCast(String urlCast) {
    this.urlCast = urlCast;
}

public String getUrlReviews() {
    return urlReviews;
}

public void setUrlReviews(String urlReviews) {
    this.urlReviews = urlReviews;
}

public String getUrlSimilar() {
    return urlSimilar;
}

public void setUrlSimilar(String urlSimilar) {
    this.urlSimilar = urlSimilar;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\nID: " + id +
            "\nTitle " + title +
            "\nDate " + releaseDateTheater +
            "\nSynopsis " + synopsis +
            "\nScore " + audienceScore +
            "\nurlThumbnail " + urlThumbnail +
            "\nurlSelf " + urlSelf +
            "\nurlCast " + urlCast +
            "\nurlReviews " + urlReviews +
            "\nurlSimilar " + urlSimilar +
            "\n";
}
```

}

Please help me out .. Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Are you sure that paresJSONResponse happens fast enought so that listMovie =paresJSONResponse(response);
            adupterBoxOffice.setMovieList(listMovie); is not null?.

Comment: Thank you friend. Here i did mistake. I change little bit in my code... ArrayList<Movies> listMovie = new ArrayList<>();
        if(response !=null|| response.length() >0 ) {


            try {
                StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
       ......................................................................But it is  also not working..

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend ..You are right ..My listMovie returned null value..Now its working like what i wanted .. Thank you again...

Comment: Cool man, can I add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

After `adupterBoxOffice.setMovieList(listMovie);`
try add `adupterBoxOffice.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution.I put some wrong key during pars the Json. That's why my ArrayList returning zero.

Many many thanks to all for helping me out.